# Which functions go with which targets in OpenGL / WebGL?

Tags: opengl-es, webgl, opengl-es-3.0

My apologies if I am phrasing this question poorly.

Is there anywhere I can find a list of OpenGL/WebGL *functions* along with the *targets* they are associated with? For example, in order to call `glDrawElements()`, a buffer must be bound to the `GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER` target. And to call `glBufferData()`, a buffer must be bound to one of several targets, including `GL_ARRAY_BUFFER`, `GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER`, `GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER`, etc...

An alternative way to approach this question would be, Is there a list of *targets* with the functions they enable?

I've downloaded the OpenGL 3.0 ES documentation files and I am pretty confident that all the information I need is contained there. But it is spread across ~280 files and I know I'm going to miss a lot of instances. I must be overlooking something because this seems like such an important aspect of OpenGL when trying to grasp the concept of "targets".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After waiting a while, I've decided to submit an answer to my own question using information I came up with from recursively grepping the reference manual.

This must surely be a partial list. Probably some mistakes. Please feel free to edit and correct if you spot any omissions or mistakes.

If anyone can submit a better, more accurate answer, I will gladly accept it with thanks.

##### Functions by target:

| Target | Functions |
| --- | --- |
| ARRAY_BUFFER | bindBuffer, bufferData, bufferSubData, copyBufferSubData, getBufferParameter, vertexAttribPointer |
| COPY_READ_BUFFER | bindBuffer, bufferData, bufferSubData, copyBufferSubData, getBufferParameter |
| COPY_WRITE_BUFFER | bindBuffer, bufferData, bufferSubData, copyBufferSubData, getBufferParameter |
| ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER | bindBuffer, bufferData, bufferSubData, copyBufferSubData, getBufferParameter, drawElements, drawElementsInstanced, drawRangeElements |
| PIXEL_PACK_BUFFER | bindBuffer, bufferData, bufferSubData, copyBufferSubData, getBufferParameter, readPixels |
| PIXEL_UNPACK_BUFFER | bindBuffer, bufferData, bufferSubData, copyBufferSubData, getBufferParameter, compressedTexImage2D, compressedTexImage3D, compressedTexSubImage2D, compressedTexSubImage3D, texImage2D, texImage3D, texSubImage2D, texSubImage3D |
| TRANSFORM_FEEDBACK_BUFFER | bindBuffer, bufferData, bufferSubData, copyBufferSubData, getBufferParameter, bindBufferBase, bindBufferRange |
| UNIFORM_BUFFER | bindBuffer, bufferData, bufferSubData, copyBufferSubData, getBufferParameter, bindBufferBase, bindBufferRange |
| TEXTURE_2D | compressedTexImage2D, compressedTexSubImage2D, texImage2D, texSubImage2D, framebufferTexture2D, bindTexture, copyTexImage2D, copyTexSubImage2D, generateMipmap, getTexParameter, texStorage2D |
| TEXTURE_3D | compressedTexImage3D, compressedTexSubImage3D, texImage3D, texSubImage3D, bindTexture, generateMipmap, getTexParameter, copyTexSubImage3D, texStorage3D |
| TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY | compressedTexImage3D, compressedTexSubImage3D, texImage3D, texSubImage3D, bindTexture, generateMipmap, getTexParameter, copyTexSubImage3D, texStorage3D |
| TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP | texImage2D, bindTexture, generateMipmap, getTexParameter, texStorage2D |
| GL_FRAMEBUFFER | framebufferTexture2D |
| READ_FRAMEBUFFER | framebufferTexture2D, bindFramebuffer, checkFramebufferStatus, framebufferRenderbuffer, framebufferTextureLayer, invalidateFramebuffer, invalidateSubFramebuffer |
| DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER | framebufferTexture2D, bindFramebuffer, checkFramebufferStatus, framebufferRenderbuffer, framebufferTextureLayer, invalidateFramebuffer, invalidateSubFramebuffer |
| RENDERBUFFER | framebufferRenderbuffer, bindRenderbuffer, renderbufferStorage, renderbufferStorageMultisample |
| TRANSFORM_FEEDBACK | bindTransformFeedback |

##### Targets by function

| Function | Targets |
| --- | --- |
| bindBuffer | ARRAY_BUFFER, COPY_READ_BUFFER, COPY_WRITE_BUFFER, ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, PIXEL_PACK_BUFFER, PIXEL_UNPACK_BUFFER, TRANSFORM_FEEDBACK_BUFFER, UNIFORM_BUFFER |
| bindBufferBase | TRANSFORM_FEEDBACK_BUFFER, UNIFORM_BUFFER |
| bindBufferRange | TRANSFORM_FEEDBACK_BUFFER, UNIFORM_BUFFER |
| bindFramebuffer | READ_FRAMEBUFFER, DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER |
| bindRenderbuffer | RENDERBUFFER |
| bindTexture | TEXTURE_2D, TEXTURE_3D, TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP |
| bindTransformFeedback | TRANSFORM_FEEDBACK |
| bufferData | ARRAY_BUFFER, COPY_READ_BUFFER, COPY_WRITE_BUFFER, ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, PIXEL_PACK_BUFFER, PIXEL_UNPACK_BUFFER, TRANSFORM_FEEDBACK_BUFFER, UNIFORM_BUFFER |
| bufferSubData | ARRAY_BUFFER, COPY_READ_BUFFER, COPY_WRITE_BUFFER, ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, PIXEL_PACK_BUFFER, PIXEL_UNPACK_BUFFER, TRANSFORM_FEEDBACK_BUFFER, UNIFORM_BUFFER |
| checkFramebufferStatus | READ_FRAMEBUFFER, DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER |
| compressedTexImage2D | PIXEL_UNPACK_BUFFER, TEXTURE_2D |
| compressedTexImage3D | PIXEL_UNPACK_BUFFER, TEXTURE_3D, TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY |
| compressedTexSubImage2D | PIXEL_UNPACK_BUFFER, TEXTURE_2D |
| compressedTexSubImage3D | PIXEL_UNPACK_BUFFER, TEXTURE_3D, TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY |
| copyBufferSubData | ARRAY_BUFFER, COPY_READ_BUFFER, COPY_WRITE_BUFFER, ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, PIXEL_PACK_BUFFER, PIXEL_UNPACK_BUFFER, TRANSFORM_FEEDBACK_BUFFER, UNIFORM_BUFFER |
| copyTexImage2D | TEXTURE_2D |
| copyTexSubImage2D | TEXTURE_2D |
| copyTexSubImage3D | TEXTURE_3D, TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY |
| drawElements | ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER |
| drawElementsInstanced | ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER |
| drawRangeElements | ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER |
| framebufferRenderbuffer | READ_FRAMEBUFFER, DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER, RENDERBUFFER |
| framebufferTexture2D | GL_FRAMEBUFFER, READ_FRAMEBUFFER, DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER, TEXTURE_2D |
| framebufferTextureLayer | READ_FRAMEBUFFER, DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER |
| generateMipmap | TEXTURE_2D, TEXTURE_3D, TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP |
| getBufferParameter | ARRAY_BUFFER, COPY_READ_BUFFER, COPY_WRITE_BUFFER, ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, PIXEL_PACK_BUFFER, PIXEL_UNPACK_BUFFER, TRANSFORM_FEEDBACK_BUFFER, UNIFORM_BUFFER |
| getTexParameter | TEXTURE_2D, TEXTURE_3D, TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP |
| invalidateFramebuffer | READ_FRAMEBUFFER, DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER |
| invalidateSubFramebuffer | READ_FRAMEBUFFER, DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER |
| readPixels | PIXEL_PACK_BUFFER |
| renderbufferStorage | RENDERBUFFER |
| renderbufferStorageMultisample | RENDERBUFFER |
| texImage2D | PIXEL_UNPACK_BUFFER, TEXTURE_2D, TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP |
| texImage3D | PIXEL_UNPACK_BUFFER, TEXTURE_3D, TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY |
| texStorage2D | TEXTURE_2D, TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP |
| texStorage3D | TEXTURE_3D, TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY |
| texSubImage2D | PIXEL_UNPACK_BUFFER, TEXTURE_2D |
| texSubImage3D | PIXEL_UNPACK_BUFFER, TEXTURE_3D, TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY |
| vertexAttribPointer | ARRAY_BUFFER |

Finally, these are all of the functions you call that do not require a target as an argument (i.e. a function that will throw if you haven't bound some object to some target):

- vertexAttribPointer
- drawElements
- drawElementsInstanced
- drawRangeElements
- readPixels